# Clipboard.Clear(), Clipboard.SetData() not working properly for rdp server

Tags: c#, windows, clipboard, remote-desktop, rdp

I was fiddling around the Clipboard class in C# for some time now. What I tried is after getting IDataObject from clipboard by using

```
IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

after that, I tried clearing the clipboard by using

```
Clipboard.Clear();
```

and then again set the dataobject into the clipboard by using

```
iData.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, iData.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false));
Clipboard.SetDataObject(iData, true, 10, 100);
```

By doing the above steps, I was just clearing and resetting the data into the clipboard, and this works without any problem in the local machine. But if I copy in local machine and paste it into a remote desktop connected machine, it fails. Is anyone willing to explain why or am I doing anything wrong?
Is there any other proper way for clearing and resetting the data into the clipboard, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is the "Clipboard" option checked under "Local Resources" for the connection options? If not no clipboard sharing is going to be happening at all. (If it is this might still fail when done programmatically, as it seems unlikely file drag and drop would be supported across remote clipboards, but it's good to check anyway.)

Comment: yes, "Clipboard" option is Checked. But still no use for this scenario.